# Git: Why does my work tree disappear after being created?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I'm trying to set up a working tree for my git repository so I can use LFS (I'm using git as version control for an Unreal project and need a way to commit large amounts of files.)

I've been trying to set up the working tree as follows:

```
$git worktree add -B lfsbranch /e/GitHub/WorkTree master
```

The command line says:

```
Preparing worktree (resetting branch 'lfsbranch'; was at 42af202)
```

And then finishes after a few seconds. I can see the folder being created in the directory, and even being filled with the contents of the master git. However, once the process is done the folder simply disappears.

I've tried to find an answer for this, but I haven't been able to come across anything, so I thought I would ask the question specifically. Why do my work trees keep disappearing?

Comment: OK, so I just realised that I was executing the command in the wrong place, I was in the git repo rather than the actual master file. Running it from /e/GitHub/Master instead of /e/GitHub/Master/.git made it work properly.